# How to contact multiple companies after the job fair

Tags: communication, job-search

I have attended a job fair last week. A few companies said that they are interested in my work and gave me their business card to contact them. I was wondering what will the best way to contact them and ask about the job or internship?

Comment: Send an email, that is why they gave you a card.

Answer (score 4):

Normally I would advise emailing them at the address on the cards. But after seeing multiple spelling and other errors in such a short question it might be best to give them a ring and see if you can arrange a meeting.

Comment: English might not be OP's mother tongue, and this is a website in English. I'd say emailing them is the way to go, double-checking there are no spelling errors.

Comment: @Charmander it's not mine either, I know well the difference between using another language and just spelling errors. One is spelling phonetically, the other is just laziness

Answer (score 2):

Unless they told you to use one specific method of contacting them, then either phone or email will work. Depending on the information on their card they could also ask you to contact them via social media or a contact method on their website.

One advantage of email is that they don't have to be near their phone and free to talk  at the moment you call. Email also is easier for them to respond to you during non-standard hours. Of course email can get lost if it is viewed as spam.

I would lean towards email.